# How can I execute a function with parameters on page loading

Tags: angular, angular7

I want to display the text 'Subscribed' if the user is subscribed and 'Subscribe' if he is not. To do that, I call from the back-end a service that provides me the object if he is subscribed and throws an error not found if he is not. Now how can I change the text on display whether he is subscribed or whether he is not.

I am working on Angular 7.

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CategoryService } from '@ikubinfo/core/services/category.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'ikubinfo-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})


export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  categories: Object;
  text: string;

  constructor(private categoryService: CategoryService, private router: Router) { 
    this.categories=[];
    this.text='';
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.categoryService.getAllCategories().subscribe(res=>{
      this.categories=res;
      console.log(this.categories);
    });
  }

 subscribe(id: number){
   this.categoryService.subscribe(id).subscribe(res=>{
   });
 }

 isSubscribed(id:number){
 return this.categoryService.isSubscribed(id).subscribe(res=>{
   this.text='Subscribed';
  },err=>{
    this.text='Subscribe';
  });
}
}
```

And the html

```html
<div class="row">

  <div class="col col-xl-6 col-lg-12" *ngFor="let category of categories">
    <ikubinfo-panel header="Category">
      <div panel-content ng-onload="isSubscribed(category.categoryId)">
        <h1>{{ category.categoryName }}</h1>
        <p>{{ category.categoryDescription }}</p>
        <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="subscribe(category.categoryId)">{{ text }}</button>
      </div>
    </ikubinfo-panel>
  </div> 


</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have an additional property isSubscribed in the Category model,

```
export interface Category {
   ... // other existing properties
   isSubscribed: boolean = false; // initializing to false by default for error case
}
```

In the *.ts file,

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.categoryService.getAllCategories().subscribe(res=>{
      this.categories=res;
      this.categories.forEach((category) => {
           this.categoryService.isSubscribed(id).subscribe(res=>{
             category.isSubscribed = true;
           });
        });
    });
}
```

In the *.html file, display the text based on this property.

```
<!-- It is better to disable the button if it is subscribed-->
<button class="btn btn-success" (click)="subscribe(category.categoryId)">{{ category.isSubscribed?'Subscribed':'Subscribe'}}</button>
```

Also, I would recommend getting the subscription flag on the initial request of getting all categories.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much. You killed it.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your isSubscribed() method like this:

```
isSubscribed(id:number) {    

    return this.categoryService.isSubscribed(id)
               .pipe(
                 //this will map your response to 'Subscribed' text
                 map(res => 'Subscribed'),
                 //this map error to 'NotSubscribed
                 catchError(error => 'Not Subscribed')
               );
  }
```

Now let's change the template like this:

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col col-xl-6 col-lg-12" *ngFor="let category of categories">
    <ikubinfo-panel header="Category">
      <div panel-content>
        <h1>{{ category.categoryName }}</h1>
        <p>{{ category.categoryDescription }}</p>
        <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="subscribe(category.categoryId)">{{ isSubscribed(category.categoryId) | async}}</button>
      </div>
    </ikubinfo-panel>
  </div> 


</div>
```

**Although I have provided the solution as per your current code. There is plenty of scope of the code improvement. You should avoid using function calls in the template in bindings [except user action i.e. button click]. Also you can avoid .subscribe() in your component class by using `async` pipe** [https://blog.angularindepth.com/tiny-angular-pipe-to-make-any-function-memoizable-f6c8fa917f2f]